# How to check given timestamp in milliseconds is 00:00 hh:mm in Scala?

Tags: scala, datetime, time

I am working in Scala recently. I learn a bit of Scala.

Now problem is, I am getting time-stamps in milliseconds contains date and time from a .csv file. I have to check those time-stamps one by one, if a time-stamp is 00:00(hh:mm), it should exclude. Under my knowledge I did like this.

```
timestamp % 86400000(milliseconds for a day) == 0
```

Is it right way of checking?

Comment: is the timestamp in UNIX epoch or miliseconds since the start of the day? Which kind of timestamp do you have to parse?

Comment: What is the timezone of the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `java.util.Calendar` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
val ts = 123456789
val cal = Calendar.getInstance
cal.setTimeInMillis(ts)
if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0)
    println("EXCLUDE")
else
    println("INCLUDE")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with JDK 8 you can use the new [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (which is heavily influenced by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)).

A possible approach that takes time zones into account can be the following:

```
import java.time.{Instant, ZoneId}
import java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException

@throws(classOf[ZoneRulesException])
def isAtMidnight(timestamp: Long, zone: String = "UTC"): Boolean = {
  val t = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneId.of(zone)).toLocalTime
  t.getHour == 0 && t.getMinute == 0
}
```